# How to solve differential equation $y'=e^{x-y} + \mu^2 y,\ y(0) = \mu$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solution of differential equation
$$y'=e^{x-y} + \mu^2 y,\ y(0) = \mu$$
given in this form
$$y(x) = v_0(x) + v_1(x) \mu + v_2(x) \mu^2 + o(\mu^2)$$
How to find $v_0, v_1, v_2$?

I have tried to place $y(x)$ into $e^{x-y}$ and write Taylor series of that:
$$e^{x-v_0}(1+(- v_1 \mu -  v_2 \mu^2) + \frac{(- v_1 \mu -  v_2 \mu^2)^2}{2!})$$
What should I do next?

Comment: Try finding $v_0(x)$ first, by setting $\mu = 0$.

Comment: @B.Mehta, $v_0 = x$, but how to find $v_1, v_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you complete the $O(μ^3)$ expansion,
$$
v_0'+μv_1'+μ^2v_2'=e^{x-v_0}\Bigl(1-μv_1-μ^2(v_2-\tfrac12v_1^2)\Bigr)+\mu^2 v_0 + O(μ^3),
$$
insert $v_0=x$ and separate the powers
\begin{align}
v_1'&=-v_1,&v_1(0)&=1,\\
v_2'&=-v_2+\tfrac12v_1^2 + v_0,&v_2(0)&=0.
\end{align}